# How can I make my div conditionally not wrap based on text content?

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph of text where each word is wrapped in a `div style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;"`. The punctuation marks are also wrapped in divs like that.

Sometimes a punctuation mark div ends up at the beginning of a line.

How can I make the divs with punctuation stick to the previous div so that the previous div wraps to the next line so I don't have punctuation starting at the beginning of a line.

```html
<span id="0" class="sentence">
<div id="0" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
1<rt></rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
<div id="1" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
 <rt></rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
<div id="2" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
最初<rt>zuìchū</rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
<div id="3" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
+<rt></rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
<div id="4" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
，<rt></rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
<div id="5" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
上帝<rt>Shàngdì</rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
<div id="6" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
+<rt></rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
<div id="7" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
创造<rt>chuàngzào</rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
<div id="8" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
了<rt>le</rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
<div id="9" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
+<rt></rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
<div id="10" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
天地<rt>tiāndì</rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
<div id="11" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
+<rt></rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
<div id="12" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
。<rt></rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
</span>
<span id="1" class="sentence">
</span>
</p>
<p id="1">
<span id="0" class="sentence">
<div id="0" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
2<rt></rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
<div id="1" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
 <rt></rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
<div id="2" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
大地<rt>dàdì</rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
<div id="3" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
混沌<rt>hùndùn</rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
<div id="4" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
苍茫<rt>cāngmáng</rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
<div id="5" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
，<rt></rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
<div id="6" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
深渊<rt>shēnyuān</rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
<div id="7" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
的<rt>de</rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
<div id="8" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
表面<rt>biǎomiàn</rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
<div id="9" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
一<rt>yī</rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
<div id="10" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
片<rt>piān</rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
<div id="11" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
黑暗<rt>hēiàn</rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
<div id="12" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
+<rt></rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
<div id="13" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
。<rt></rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
</span>
<span id="1" class="sentence">
<div id="0" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
上帝<rt>Shàngdì</rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
<div id="1" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
发出<rt>fāchū</rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
<div id="2" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
的<rt>de</rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
<div id="3" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
动力<rt>dònglì</rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
<div id="4" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
+<rt></rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
</div>
<div id="5" style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<h3>
<ruby>
运行<rt>yùnxíng</rt>
</ruby>
</h3>
```

Comment: can you add classes to that? If it is possible there might be a solution.

Comment: Of course, divs aren't permitted children of paragraphs or spans...it's invalid HTML. Not related though. Basically though, **you can't**.

Comment: Oh...and you can't repeat IDs either,

Comment: I can add classes. I have full control.

Comment: When I said "a paragraph of text where each word is wrapped in a div", I didn't mean `<p>`, I meant  `¶`.

Comment: @webmagnets sorry to spaml here but the question you asked on promasters will most likely get moved here, but here is a link on Jsfiddle I made for you. https://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/Lnwmwf2k/